# Android - Detect OutgoingCallReceiver when call ends

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

Hey I've got a OutgoingCallReceiver, which detect when a outgoing call happends. If a special number has been dialed, it's starting an service.

But now, i've got a problem that i need to stop the same service when the that outgoing call has ended.

Is there a nice way to do it? Thanks!!

```
ublic class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    boolean ringing = false, offhook = false;

    Intent i = new Intent(arg0, MyServices.class);
    Intent ii = new Intent(arg0, RecorderService.class);
    Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();

    if(null == bundle)
            return;


    String phonenumber = arg1.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
    Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());


    if(phonenumber.equals("#1234") || bundle.toString().equals("#1234")) { 

        ii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startService(ii);
    }


    String action = arg1.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(action)) {

    } else{
        arg0.stopService(ii);
    }



    } 
}
```

There is the code.

Thanks for all the help, and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Class MyService:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private CallListener call = null;

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    call = new CallListener(getApplicationContext());
    call.start();
    return(START_STICKY);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    call.stop();
    call.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Class CallListener:

```
public class CallListener {

private CallStateListener callStateListener = null;
private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver = null;

public CallListener(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
}

private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
      switch (state) {
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        doSomething1();
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        doSomething2();
        break;
      case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        doSomething3();
        break;
      }
    }
}

public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         doSomething4();
    }
}

public void start() {
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    context.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public void stop() {
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

    context.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
}
}
```

Comment: Should that code be in a new class? I'm pretty new with Android, so more clearer code would be very good. Thanks!

Comment: Should i put the Start Activity in the OutgoingReceiver? and put stop(); in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK?

Comment: Could you post some more expample? I don't really understand. I just want the activity to start when dialing #1234, and end the activity when the call is done. Thanks so much for all help!

Comment: The code doesn't work, or i'm doing something wrong. Sorry.. I understand TelephonyManager, but not the PendingIntent.getActivity..

Comment: I copied your code, and put PendingIntent.getActivity in one of the states. Isn't there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Not that comes to mind. To kick of your Activity, you probably find a lot of examples with Google searching for PendingIntent.getActivity...

Comment: Should the OutgoingReceiver replace my old OutgoingReceiver? Thanks for all the help !!

Comment: and where should i start and end the activity?? (:

Comment: PendingIntent.getActivity will start the Activity, you pressing the back button will end the Activity. Replace your code.

Comment: It's not an Activity, its an background service. Sorry if i wasn't clear. So i just want start the background service when dial the special number, and end the background service when the call is done. How should i do this? Thanks, you're the best.

Comment: PendingIntent.getService and/or startService/stopService

Comment: Thansk so much, last thing where should i put the start service and stop service in the code to work?? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this code, but still not sure where to put startService/stopService, Could you help me?

Comment: You should be able to get the code running, otherwise I suggest you read a couple of Android books to pick up the concepts.